# script-write dict and write it to file then load

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, enums

Edit: I reworked my whole post and implemented my actual code since i was not able to point at my problem. Thanks to everyone who has been contributing, i hope this version is alot clearer.

My goal is to do big number evaluation on poker hand ranges (e.g. i have TT and you have AA,KK or AK). Therefor there would be two input strings "TT" and "AA, KK, AK".
These strings are seperated into the individual parts ("AA", "KK", "AK") and then used as keys in my dict. The dict is structured as key : array( (card, card), ...) objects.

Below is the Code to create the dictionary and write it into a file. While the dictionary created in the upper part works fine i cannot eyport it to a file to later import it into another program without getting syntax/name errors.

```
from enum import Enum #need python 3.4
import operator
from random import shuffle


class CardValue(Enum):  #name = value
    A = 14
    K = 13
    Q = 12
    J = 11
    T = 10
    N = 9
    E = 8
    S = 7
    F = 6

    def __str__(self):
        if self.value > 9:
            return "{}".format(self.name)
        else:
            return "{}".format(str(self.value))

class CardSuit(Enum):
    c = 1
    d = 2
    h = 3 
    s = 4

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

class Card(tuple):    #tuples are unchangable

    def __new__(cls, value, suit):    #new is immutable
        assert isinstance(value, CardValue)    #assert stops if following is False, isinstance checks if value is an item of CardValue
        assert isinstance(suit, CardSuit)
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (value, suit))    #return tuple should be similar to self.value, self.suit

    @property   #i need to understand this...
    def value(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def suit(self):
        return self[1]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}{}".format(str(self.value), self.suit.name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return(str(self))

    def __setattr__(self, *ignored):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __delattr__(self, *ignored):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Deck: #holds all Card class Objects that are not drawn
    def __init__(self): #creates a new shuffled Deck containing all Cards
        self.cards = [
            Card(value, suit) for value in CardValue for suit in CardSuit
        ]
        #shuffle(self.cards)

    def setCard(self, value, suit): #tries to deal a specific  card from the deck    
        if Card(value, suit) in self.cards: #if successful returns the Card and removes from deck 
            self.removeCard(Card(value, suit).value, Card(value, suit).suit)
            return Card(value, suit)
        else:   
            print('not in deck')

    def topCard(self):
        cardone = self.cards.pop()
        #self.removeCard(cardone.value, cardone.suit)
        return(cardone)

    def removeCard(self, value, suit):  #tries to remove a specific Card from the deck // future dead cards
        if Card(value, suit) in self.cards:
            self.cards.remove(Card(value, suit))
        else:
            print('not in deck')

#this creates the dict in python
helpmemore = [] #temp array to store card combinations in
mylazydict = {} #dict to store arrays of card combinations in   "AK" : []
for valueone in CardValue:
    for valuetwo in CardValue:
        for suitone in CardSuit:
            for suittwo in CardSuit:
                if valueone != valuetwo or suitone != suittwo:  #no double cards
                    helpmemore.append((Card(valueone, suitone), Card(valuetwo, suittwo)))
        mylazydict[str(valueone)+str(valuetwo)] = helpmemore
        helpmemore = []

#this saves the dict to a file
dotdot = 0
input2_dict = open("input2_dict.py", "w")
input2_dict.write("input2_dict = {"+"\n")
for line in mylazydict:
    input2_dict.write("\t"+"\""+line+"\" : "+str(mylazydict[line]))
    if dotdot != len(mylazydict)-1:
        input2_dict.write(",")
    input2_dict.write("\n")
    dotdot += 1
input2_dict.write("\t}")
input2_dict.close()
```

Error:

```
  File "input2_dict.py", line 7                                                                                             "A9" : [(Ac, 9c), (Ac, 9d), (Ac, 9h), (Ac, 9s), (Ad, 9c), (Ad, 9d), (Ad, 9h), (Ad, 9s), (Ah, 9c), (Ah, 9d), (Ah, 9h), (Ah, 9s), (As, 9c), (As, 9d), (As, 9h), (As, 9s)],                                                                                      ^                                                                                                     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Guessing it is because of the 9 being and integer and just taking the first line i get an name error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "input2_dict.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                "AA" : [(Ac, Ad), (Ac, Ah), (Ac, As), (Ad, Ac), (Ad, Ah), (Ad, As), (Ah, Ac), (Ah, Ad), (Ah, As), (As, Ac), (As, Ad), (As, Ah)],                                                                                                            NameError: name 'Ac' is not defined
```

Then i want to check if the cards from the dict entry are still in Deck.cards

Comment: Putting this the best I can, using a dict you will be overwriting values with identical keys. I suggest using something that relates to a student such as a students `id` for the key. Something like `{id: : [(Taste.VANILLA, Taste.VANILLA)]}` and their id would be something unique to each student. Also your explanation at the top is very misleading to what your code actually does

Comment: thank you for your response, ill edit my post and try to make things clearer

Comment: You already have *exactly what you want*. You are just confusing Python syntax to reference an enum value with the debugging representation of that value. `Taste.CHOCOLATE` is a Python expression for the enum object, and when you echo that object or put it in a tuple and then echo the tuple, is `<Taste.CHOCOLATE: 4>`.

Comment: So **there is no problem to solve here**. Seeing `<Taste.CHOCOLATE: 4>` when you print your dictionary means it is all working. Note that you are simply printing  *representations helpful for debugging*, not something you'd want to show end-users. If you need to format your objects for neat user-friendly output, write code to do so, don't try to bend representation output to that use.

Comment: But when im writing my dict like the first example (my_dict_one) im getting syntax errors, so how am i solving this then?

Comment: Of my 3 given examples i can produce the first and second one easily but only the second and third one can be executed properly, whilst the 2nd (strings) dont help me at all

Comment: If there is some other reason why you want `Taste.CHOCOLATE` to appear instead of `<Taste.CHOCOLATE: 4>`, you need to make that clear in your question. Right now it is not clear why you would want this. If all you need is for `(Taste.CHOCOLATE, FatAmount.LOW) in myMenu.drinks` work, then *that already works*.

Comment: @cdol: your first example is showing debugging output, not Python syntax. Don't use that to create a new dictionary with the same value.

Comment: I guess that is what got me into trouble. What would be the proper way to create this dict? Ive been basically printing the output to another file...

Comment: is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Why are you doing all this? What is the real goal? Why are you writing all this to a file in the first place? I think you may want to reconsider the steps that led you to here. (And a guess, are you trying to save and recreate the python objects?)

Comment: Im trying to do big number evaluations for poker hand ranges. The imput strings consist of "XY", "XsYc" and "XYo"/"XYs". Basically the key "XY" as "AceKing" has the value of 16 Card Pairs (aces*kings ; 4 suits). XYs for example means two cards of the same suit.

Comment: Then i want to check if the returned card pairs are still possible to be drawn, hence if both single cards are still in the card pool. In my example Menu is the deck and Drink is a card.

Comment: Rather than writing your own code to serialize this information to a file, you might want to look into existing serialization libraries, such as pickle, json, or yaml. Also, it's not clear *why* serializing this information to a file is necessary in the first place, as @ParitoshSingh noted above. Your replies to that question described your program's intent, but they did not explain why writing the information to the file system is needed to achieve the program's goals. Are you certain it's needed?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I cannot say that it is essential to serialize to a file but since im only a beginner coder trying to get into big number evaluation im trying to reduce the code that has to be looped over as much as possible. Thats why i try to implement dicts where i possibly can